# How to read and write to a file (Javascript) in ui automation?

Tags: javascript, json, instruments, ios-ui-automation

I want to identify few properties during my run and form a json object which I would like to write to a ".json"file and save it on the disk.

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var properties = new Object();
var jsonObjectToRecord = {"properties":properties}
jsonObjectToRecord.properties.name = "My App"
UIALogger.logMessage("Pretty Print TEST Log"+jsonObjectToRecord.properties.name);
var str = JSON.stringify(jsonObjectToRecord)
UIALogger.logMessage(str);
// -- CODE TO WRITE THIS JSON TO A FILE AND SAVE ON THE DISK --
```

I tried :

```
// Sample code to see if it is possible to write data
// onto some file from my automation script
function WriteToFile()
 {

    set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");  
    set s = fso.CreateTextFile("/Volumes/DEV/test.txt", True);
    s.writeline("HI");
    s.writeline("Bye");
    s.writeline("-----------------------------");
    s.Close();
 }
```

AND

```
function WriteFile()
{
    // Create an instance of StreamWriter to write text to a file.
    sw = new StreamWriter("TestFile.txt");
    // Add some text to the file.
    sw.Write("This is the ");
    sw.WriteLine("header for the file.");
    sw.WriteLine("-------------------");
    // Arbitrary objects can also be written to the file.
    sw.Write("The date is: ");
    sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
    sw.Close();
}
```

But still unable to read and write data to file from ui automation instruments

Possible Workaround ??
To redirect to the stdout if we can execute a terminal command from my ui automation script. So can we execute a terminal command from the script ?

Haven't Tried :
1. Assuming we can include the library that have those methods and give it a try .

Comment: what kind of UI automation tool you are using, is this script is executed in normal browser?

Comment: @ZigmaEmpire I tried to execute normal browser script which in my instruments script

Comment: is this script is currently running on a browser like google chrome, firefox? or what?

Comment: @ZigmaEmpire No it isn't the first part runs on ui automation instruments which worked fine the WriteToFile is what I am unable to do

Comment: @ZigmaEmpire looking for a solution in similar lines where I can write onto a file from my automation script. Please ask me If I am not clear , Thank you :)

Comment: I was asking that, is your automation script is a normal javascript browser or some specialized testing tools? Many Automation scripts can be written javascript as well which will not run on a Browser..... if you answer this question then I can provide the solution for you..... please tell me your test automation tool **Name** and how you are running it?

Comment: @Zigma Empire Xcode -> Instruments -> UIAutomation

Comment: Please find my answer, you cannot simply do all JavaScript in UIAutomation, you have to use 3rd party testing tools, You can find the Selenium URL where you can find the documentations and downloads.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions are good, But the XCode UI Automation script is not a full JavaScript.

I don't think you can simply program a normal browser based JavaScript in the XCode UI Automation script.

```
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

Is not a JavaScript, it is VBScript which will only work in Microsoft Platforms and testing tools like QTP.

```
Scripting.FileSystemObject
```

Is an ActiveX object which only exists in Microsoft Windows

Only few JavaScript functions like basic Math, Array,...etc..Are provided by the Apple JavaScript library, so you are limited to use only the classes provided here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/

If you want to do more scripting then Try Selenium IOS Driver http://ios-driver.github.io/ios-driver/

Answer (score 0):

Hey so this is something that I was looking into for a project but never fully got around to implementing so this answer will be more of a guide of what to do than step by step copy and paste.

First you're going to need to create a bash script that writes to a file. This can be as simple as

```
!/bin/bash
echo $1 >> ${filename.json}
```

Then you call this from inside your Xcode Instruments UIAutomation tool with

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var host = target.host();

var result = host.performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout("your/script/path", ["Object description in JSON format"], 5);
```

Then after your automation ends you can load up the file path on your computer to look at the results.

EDIT: This will enable to write to a file line by line but the actual JSON formatting will be up to you. Looking at some examples I don't think it would be difficult to implement but obviously you'll need to give it some thought at first.